# What are good pedagogical introductions to entanglement distillation?

Tags: entanglement, resource-request, locc-operation, state-distillation

I have a basic understanding of what entanglement distillation entails, up to the typical subspace projection protocol described in Nielsen & Chuang, and I would like to read more on the subject. In particular, I'm interested in protocols that deal with the general case of a mixed shared state.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble finding a good pedagogical introduction to the topic. Can anyone point me to something like that?

Comment: Try Mark Wilde's (Quantum Information Theory) book. While reading, just keep the main idea, an overview of the protocol, at the back of your mind. Sometimes taking an explicit example and working through it helps to cement the understanding, since most text will only talk about general case with variables.